# Cake Php auth problem

Tags: cakephp, authentication

HI,

I have a problem with cake php built in auth - i cannot log in ...

1)user  is added through app control pannel and hashed using $this->auth->password('xxx') - i've checked it's corrent in db

2)security salt is not emtpy

3) in action User/Login data['User']['password'] is empty  (i don't know if this is correct but i've read that Auth remove content of data['password'] or data['User']['password'] - am I correct?

4) db has table users with fields username and password

After i'm trying to login $session->flash('auth') says:

> Login failed. Invalid username or
>   password.

but beforeFilter  in AppController i've set

> $this->Auth->loginError = 'No, you
>   fool!  Thats not the right password!';

So what can be wrong? :(

Answer (score 4):

Turn on debugging and check what queries are generated.
If none, you probably have something wrong in your view.
If there are any, then pick the hashed password it checks against and update password in db.
If you succeed everything should work fine.

Setting first user is a bit tricky.

Comment: @givanse - I am having this error (no query generated). Do you know what might cause there to be no query?

Answer (score 2):

**Don't add:**

```
function beforeSave (){

    if(isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = Security::hash($this->data[$this->alias]['password'], null, true);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**If you have the following script in app_controller:**

var $components = array('Auth', 'Email');

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->fields = array(
        'username' => 'email',
        'password' => 'password'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have entered

```
function beforeFilter(){
   parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

in your `UsersController`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your database password column has the correct datatype, i.e. `char(40)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be in the POST'd data array. If the `data['User']['password']` field is empty, I think you might have found your problem. IIRC, the Auth component does an automatic *hash* of the password. But I believe that `$this->data['User']['password']` should not be empty (in the controller) -- it just won't be in cleartext.

Check your form to make sure that your input names are correct.  Also, like niteria suggested, try checking out the SQL code in the debug dump to see what credentials are getting checked against the database (you can make a call to `$this->Auth->password('somestring')` to find out what the hashed password should be, once you have your salt applied).

GL!